# What are the most well-understood vocal animal languages?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling, language, animal-cognition, linguistics

There are many examples of [animal language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_language) that involve vocal pattens or "grammar".
For example, there is the the [Bee dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waggle_dance), bird songs, whale songs, dogs.
Bird vocalization includes both bird calls and bird songs. There are Parrots, hummingbirds and songbirds.

What are the most well-understood vocal animal languages?

Comment: I imagine quantifying "well-understood" would be difficult. Does this list of well-studied non-primate animal languages meet your needs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_language#Non-primates:_studied_examples